# IP/hostname whitelist way for a call to API from openshift

Tags: api, containers, openshift, redhat, whitelist

This is more of a how-to question , as i am still exploring openshift.

We have an orchestrator running out of openshift which calls to a REST API written in Flask hosted on apache/RHEL.

While our end point is token authenticated - we wanted to add a second level of restriction by allowing access from a whitelisted source of hosts.

But given the concept of openshift, that can span a container across any (number of ) server across its cluster.

What is the best way to go about whitelisting the action from a cluster of computers?

I tried to take a look at [External Load Balancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/%20%22Load%20Balancer%20on%20Kubernetes) for my the orchestrator service.

```
 clusterIP: 172.30.65.163
  externalIPs:
    - 10.198.40.123
    - 172.29.29.133
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  loadBalancerIP: 10.198.40.123
  ports:
    - nodePort: 30768
      port: 5023
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 5023
  selector:
    app: dbrun-x2
    deploymentconfig: dbrun-x2
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
      - ip: 172.29.29.133
```

So I am unsure is - what is the IP I am expected to see on the other side [ my API apache access logs ] with this setup?

or

Does this LoadBalancer act as gateway only for incoming calls to openshift.

sorry about the long post - would appreciate some inputs

Comment: LoadBalancer and ingress is incoming, look at egress. https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/how-enable-static-egress-ip-red-hat-openshift-container-platform